# BehaviorSubject: next is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying share data between sibling components and do this via a shared service. When the first component loads, it retrieves a list of Servers from my API and fills a select-box with all the retrieved servers. Now I want to notify my other component when the user selected a new Server so I can display it's details.

This is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {
    servers: Server[] = [];
    selectedServer = new BehaviorSubject<Server>(null);

    setServers(servers: Server[]) {
        this.servers = servers;
    }

}
```

Component with the select-box:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-servers-select',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Server</label>
      <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="this.dashboardService.selectedServer" (ngModelChange)="change($event)">
        <option disabled>-- Select server --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let server of servers" [ngValue]="server">{{server.Name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./servers-select.component.css'],
  providers: [ServerService]
})
export class ServersSelectComponent implements OnInit {
  servers: Server[] = [];

  constructor(private serverService: ServerService, private dashboardService: DashboardService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.serverService
      .getServers()
      .subscribe(s => {
        this.servers = s;
        this.dashboardService.setServers(s);
        console.log(s);
      },
      e => console.log(e));

  }

  // todo: pass to dashboard component
  public change = (event: any) => {
    console.log(event);
    this.dashboardService.selectedServer.next(event);
  }

}
```

Detail component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-server-details',
  template: `
  <section>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Description</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="server">
  </div>
</section>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./server-details.component.css']
})
export class ServerDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  private server: Server = null;

  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.selectedServer.subscribe((value: Server) => {
      console.log(value + 'lalalal');
      this.server = value;
    });
  }

}
```

When I select a new Server, the change() method gets called correctly, but throws the following error in the console:

> ERROR TypeError: _this.dashboardService.selectedServer.next is not a function
>       at ServersSelectComponent.change (servers-select.component.ts:39)

The subscribe seems to work already since I get 'nulllalalal' in my console. What am I missing?

EDIT: 
- I am using angular 5 and rxjs 5.5.2
- In my DashboardService, I import BehaviorSubject as follows:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```

Comment: can you show from where you are importing behavioursubject in your dashboard service class

Comment: @KaranGarg See my edit :)

Comment: can you try this import import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

Comment: Could you try to type your variable like `selectedServer: BehaviorSubject<Server> = new BehaviorSubject(null);`

Comment: Dont import from rxjs/Rx

Comment: @KaranGarg I'm not going to import everything (+ it's not working, tested it for the sake of it)

Comment: @trichetriche no success

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ServersSelectComponent`'s template you have:

```
[(ngModel)]="this.dashboardService.selectedServer"
```

This overrides the `selectedServer` service property with a value of one of the options.

If you want to emit changes via a RxJS Subject you definitely don't want to be using `[(ngModel)]` and trigger the change manually with `(change)` event listener like `(change)="change($event)"`.

Comment: Or you could use the async pipe in your ngModel I think, with `[(ngModel)]="this.dashboardService.selectedServer | async"`, since selectedServer is an Observable. Anyways, good work finding that @martin !

Comment: @martin Thank you, this was indeed the issue! However, I don't see how to get the selected Server now, since in my previous code, the $event would equal my Server, and now it is an Event object. Do I now just look what the current selected option is?

Comment: @trichetriche No, I really doubt this would work. The `async` just subscribes to the preceding expression and prints its result. it doesn't emit anything anywhere.

Comment: @ChristopheLoeys You can subscribe to the Subject in the component and use `[(ngModel)]` with a local property. Or maybe using just `[ngModel]="this.dashboardService.selectedServer | async"` could work too but I've never tried it

Comment: @ChristopheLoeys See this https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel

Comment: @martin thanks a lot for your help, I have learned a lot from this as an angular newbie. :)